# Google Charts not loading on modal popup

Tags: jquery, charts, modal-dialog

I'm trying to load a Google Chart via a modal popup. The code that I have works OK via a standalone page, however when loaded via a popup, I receive a "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" error.

popup.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Price'],
        [new Date(2014,9,18,14,20,41), 2.30],[new Date(2015,0,06,07,12,04), 1.00]
        ]);
        function hide_chart() 
        {
            view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.hideColumns([1]); 
            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data);
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
      drawChart();
    });
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Jquery to load popup:

```
$('#modal').load("/pages/popup.html", function () {
});
```

I have tried:

1. moving https://www.google.com/jsapi from popup.html to index.html
2. Calling https://www.google.com/jsapi via getScript function before calling drawChart

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards